# Run Grails on HTTPS

Tags: grails, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to run Grails on https on `localhost`. I have already configured HTTPS and can see the Apache page when `localhost:443` is hit. Currently Grails runs on `8080`.  When I try running grails with `grails -Dserver.port.https=443 run-app -https`, I get `Permission denied`. I know this requires some kind of root access below port `1024`. But when I try `sudo grails run-app`, this gives me command not found.

Any possible solutions?

Comment: which version of Grails are you on?

Comment: Grails version is 2.3.11

Comment: according to documentation http://docs.grails.org/2.3.11/guide/single.html#understandingControllersAndActions you should use `grails.server.port.https` - you are missing `grails.` in beginning of option

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's a bad idea to run your web app as root. Practically speaking, your app becomes super exploitable. Any security flaw in your setup will suddenly give the attacker full root access to the server.

This is why it's more common to do one of the following:

- Run a proxy such as apache or nginx or haproxy on port 443 with https, and grails on port 8080 without https. Set up the proxy to forward all requests to your grails app at 8080. Make sure the grails app only listens to localhost, so you can't go directly to yoursite.com:8080.
- Run Grails at 8080, with https, only listening on localhost, and set up a netfilter/iptables rule to forward traffic on 443 to localhost 8080.

The two setups are essentialy the same. The main difference is whether to use a user level setup, or rely on an OS level service such as netfilters.

Comment: you solved my confusion to quite an extent. I will tell you more specific. Basically, I have a bank transaction request being emitted from grails view. That request requires only https. So the above is true for incoming. What about when I post? How do I redirect outgoing via 443?

Comment: Define "outgoing"... if you're using HttpBuilder or some such to connect to an outside URL, just make sure that URL starts with "https".